# `az devops login` with `az login` still requests personal access token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have started using Azure Pipelines with GitHub backed account and created my first organization. I do not have any projects in that organization. I also do not have any subscriptions on `portal.azure.com`. I want to list available project in my organization using Azure CLI - basically - to get an empty list, because there are no projects yet.

When I type

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions
```

I login successfully using a browser. But all the other Azure CLI commands that I issue afterwards will fail, and ask to login. What's in the name?

After a successful `az login`, when I type

```
az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/my-org-name-i-will-not-tell-you/
```

it prompts me for `token`, which is confusing, because from [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows):

> If you have already signed in with az login interactively or using user name and password, then you don't have to provide a token as az devops commands now support sign in through az login.

I am confused, why I cannot login. Do I need to create a subscription on `portal.azure.com` to login? I don't want to do it, and don't' see why that will be necessary for my task.

Comment: Are the following replies helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT unfortunately, no. The answers just cite the documentation. I am using `az devops login` with a personal access token to login.

Comment: If you use `az devops login` command, token is required.

Answer (score 2):

If you login through

`az login --allow-no-subscriptions`

there is no need to call `az devops login` as you have access to Azure DevOps. Anf if you want to configure default organization, you can always use [az devops configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_devops_configure)

But it looks like mistake on CLI or documentation. I would recommend you create an issue for this page on GitHub.

Comment: The `az login` seems been disabled recently. I works before, but I can't use it anymore if I login with `az login`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates if you have already signed in with `az login` interactively or using user name and password, then you don't have to provide a token as `az devops` commands now support sign in through `az login`. In my opinion, the `az devops` commands here doesn't include `az devops login` command, as you don't need to run `az devops login` command after you running `az login` command.